# How to take a screen shot with status bar contents in android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screenshot

I have a requirement that I have to take a screenshot of the current window in android. 
This is the code am using,

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View screenView = rootView.getRootView();
screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

by using this I could get the application screen shot, but the status bar contents are missing (bluetooth icon, battery status etc).
How can I take a screenshot of the current Android phone window programmatically (including status bar contents)? 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

On Android 5.0+, use the media projection APIs to take a screenshot of the device screen. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter), as the process is somewhat involved.

On older Android devices, there is no support for programmatic screenshots of the device screen.

Comment: @AndroidDev: The media projection APIs definitely work on Android 8.0 and higher.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Note that I updated the link to [a newer version of that sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter), which I am fairly certain works on Android 8.0.