# Best solution for background screenshot

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want the application in the background to be able to take a screenshot and save the result to the clipboard. Is there an optimal solution to this problem?

Comment: Try the suggested answers for [taking a screenshot using a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097901/16653700) and [taking a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/16653700).

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the following code examples

```
public class HelperScreenShot {

    public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(View v) {
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        v.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return b;
    }

    public static Bitmap takeScreenshotOfRootView(View v) {
        return takeScreenshot(v.getRootView());
    }

    public static boolean takeScreenshotAndSaveIi(View v, String filename) {
        return storeScreenshot(takeScreenshot(v.getRootView()), filename);
    }

    public static boolean storeScreenshot(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

        if (!isExternalStorageReadable()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            return false;
        }

        OutputStream out;
        try {
            File dir = getDownloadStorageDir("ScreenShots");
            File imageFile = new File(dir, filename + ".jpg");
            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                imageFile.createNewFile();
            }
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            // choose JPEG format
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(G.context, new String[]{imageFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // manage exception ...
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // manage exception ...
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }

    private static File getDownloadStorageDir(String fileName) {
        // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileName);

        if (!Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).exists()) {
            new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath()).mkdirs();
        }

        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdir();
        }

        return storageDir;
    }
}

   private Single<Boolean> loadImage() {
        Date date = new Date();
        filename = "receipt" + date.getTime();
        return Single.just(HelperScreenShot.takeScreenshotAndSaveIi(binding.v, filename));
    }
```

private void getScreenshot() {

```
loadImage()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {
                disposables.add(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Boolean s) {
                if (s) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.v, getResources().getString(R.string.picture_save_to_galary), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.navigation_drawer_open), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "ScreenShots/" + filename + ".jpg");
                            Log.d("amini", "onClick: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(
                                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ?
                                            FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file) :
                                            Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*")
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                    snackbar.show();
                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.v, getResources().getString(R.string.str_frag_sync_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), v -> snackbar.dismiss());
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {

            }
        });
```

}